# Why does this statement union RowIDs from a table and a dummy table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am working on uplifting an application from Camel and myBatis to Spring boot and Jooq.

There is a very odd sql statement that is nested in our application's merge statement's using function. I don't understand the purpose of this statement, whoever wrote it is no longer with the company.

Inside the Merge's using portion, it is effectively like

```
Select A, B, C, D FROM (
    Select ROWID as RID, A, B, C, D FROM TableA TA WHERE A = var
    UNION ALL
    Select ROWID, null, null, null, null FROM dual
WHERE ROWID >= 1
```

The ROWID is not used in any the match statements, so the reason it is here makes no sense to me at all. Though I don't have much knowledge with merge statements to begin with.

Edit: the Using's On condition is to match sure A is equal to var, as var is a variable that is sent in through the function that triggers the sql. Basically it is just `ON A = var`

Answer (score 0):

The RowID is used in the last line. (WHERE ROWID >=1).

In order to get UNION ALL working, the number of columns must be the same.

For your question, it depends on the program logic after you fetch the query. Since all we can see here two tables are merge.

For example TableA has ROWID of 1,2,3, and "dual" table has ROWID of 1,2,3. The result (the merged table) will show 1,1,2,2,3,3.

It is more important to understand the program handles the result as you can find out why the old statement does the UNION ALL.

Comment: But why is there a UNION ALL?

Comment: As the old statement would like to join records from two tables together. However you cannot use JOIN as it is different. Please see details below:
https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-join-and-a-union/

Comment: Sorry, but I think I am not being very clear with my question.

I am trying to understand why you would union the two tables, one table is a copy of everyone on the table + rowid, while the other is from a Dummy Table with only null values and a row id returned.

It just does not make a lick of sense why this logic was coded like this. Espically since the outer query does not show the rowid.

Comment: Updated the answer to have more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the author wanted to guarantee that the query will return at least one row. (or exactly one row)

If

```
Select ROWID as RID, A, B, C, D FROM TableA TA WHERE A = var
```

returns nothing (zero rows, nothing is found), then `UNION ALL` will append the row of NULLs and it would be returned.

I'm not familiar with Oracle, so I'm not really sure what `WHERE ROWID >= 1` achieves.
Maybe it is to guarantee that the result set would always have exactly one row.